# Ping mechanism using PJSIP

Tags: ios, sip, ping, pjsip, pjsua2

How to find the sip server and port is reachable using pjsip library? 
I have been advised to use `pjsip_options_method`, but I don't know how to use this and if you have any better solution to suggest, please do here.

Comment: With SIP, to find out if a (proxy's) port is reachable, you have to send a request to that port. Most likely an OPTIONS or REGISTER request, but any one will do.

Comment: how to send OPTIONS using pjsip library? Do you have any sample request?

Answer (score 1):

Pjsip provides functionality to help you build a complete SIP application more easily. But if all you want to know is if a SIP server is running behind a certain port then maybe using pjsip is a bit of overkill. Especially if you are unfamiliar with it.

You could just send a UDP packet containing an OPTIONS request to the port. If a SIP server is running it will respond with an OPTIONS response.

[RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-11) describes how to compose an OPTIONS request/response and provides some examples.

If you find yourself a (free) UDP packet sender/receiver application on the internet you will be in business in no time.

Comment: Thanks for the info.